# Plotting mean value of barchart in same figure with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of different cereals and want to plot their calories as a barplot. Now I also want to plot the mean value of the calorie values as a lineplot into the same figure as the barplot. I had the idea to put the mean value into a 1x1 dataframe by its own but I got the error

> "None of [Index(['mean'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

But I'm not determined to that approach.
I was unsuccessful in finding any solution for myself. Is there any?

My code inculding the calculation of the mean value but without showing it in the figure:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("cereal.csv")
mn = df["calories"].mean()
df.plot.bar(x="name", y="calories")
```

Comment: Can you please post the dataset (or an extract) in a format that can be copied easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well you have a few bars and you would like a single horizontal line for the mean? You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("cereal.csv")
mn = df["calories"].mean()
ax = df.plot.bar(x="name", y="calories")
ax.axhline(mn, ls=':')
```